# This.Task() to VB get a error, how to fix it?

Tags: c#, vb.net

For C# code

```
public Action Task { get; set; }

this.Task();
```

But in VB:

```
 Public Property Task() As Action
        Get
            Return m_Task
        End Get
        Set(value As Action)
            m_Task = Value
        End Set
    End Property
 Me.Task()
```

Will not work.
How to fix this problem?

Comment: "will not work" is extremely vague. What *exactly* goes wrong?

Comment: Just an FYI - You don't mention which version of VS your using but VB has had [auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589(v=vs.100).aspx) since VS2010 upwards so your could would look like `Public Property Task as Action`.

Comment: It will raise the following compiler error: *Property access must assign to the property or use its value.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
Me.Task()()
```

instead of

```
Me.Task()
```

---

When accessing a property in VB.Net you can provide the parentheses or omit them, hence

```
Me.Task() = Sub() Console.WriteLine("123")
```

is equivalent to

```
Me.Task = Sub() Console.WriteLine("123")
```

Therefore, if you simply write

```
Me.Task()
```

the compiler assumes a property access here and expects you to either use its value or assign a new one. So you have to use a second pair of parentheses to use the value of the property and call the delegate.